# Error in R package installation: installation of package had non-zero exit status

Tags: r

I tried to install "gmm" package in R. However, this message was displayed, I can't use gmm package.

My R version is 3.4.4. What should I do?

```
 警告:   命令 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="gmm.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)' OBJECTS="lambda_met.o src.o"' の実行は状態 127 を持ちました 
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gmm'
* removing 'C:/Users/sejym/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/gmm'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\sejym\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\Rtmps3RZQi/downloaded_packages/gmm_1.6-5.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gmm’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\Rtmps3RZQi\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: You should update R. v3.4.4 is quite ancient now.

Comment: Adding to Phil's advice, after you update R, suggest updating all of your packages:`update.packages(ask = FALSE)`

Comment: It is definitely true that your life will be easier all the way along if you can install a more recent version of R. If there is some reason that you absolutely can't (it does happen), then you probably need to install https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools34.exe first.  It would help a bit if you can translate your error messages to English ...

Comment: I didn't know the latest version is 4.03. After updating R version, I could install gmm package. Thank you!